# how to Differentiate Expansion Title title from the rest dropdown content, I want title to have different background color than the dropdown content

Tags: flutter

I attached the Images in this post. to gives you detail information  of what I want to achieve??? I Trying to achieve like the image below.[image]

Is it possible to add a shadow to title to make it above the dropdown Content????

I am try to make the dropdown content is looks  below the Title how I can achieve that??? if there is any way to make the title look above the dropdown content it have please help me??

```
 body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: Family.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ExpansionTile(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
    
                  title: Text(
                    "HEADER HERE",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        //color: isExpanded ? Colors.pink : Colors.teal,
                        ),
                  ),
                
    
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                        //  color: HexColor("FFF1CC93"),
                        title: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          child: Image.asset(imageList[index]),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                Family[index],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  color: Colors.teal.shade900,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: width,
                                child: Text(
                                  Family[index],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                    color: Colors.grey[500],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )),
                  ],
                );
              }),
```

Answer (score 0):

please test this below code, i think you should use `Theme` on parent of `ExpansionTile` widget

```dart
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: Family.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(cardColor: Colors.red),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.red,
          title: Text(
            "HEADER HERE",
            style: TextStyle(
                //color: isExpanded ? Colors.pink : Colors.teal,
                ),
          ),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
                //  color: HexColor("FFF1CC93"),
                title: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  child: Image.asset(imageList[index]),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        Family[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.teal.shade900,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        child: Text(
                          Family[index],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            color: Colors.grey[500],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }),
```

Comment: it doesn't work as I want ? Can you see the image i attached above that is what i am trying to achieve, I want to separate title from dropdown contents

Comment: @beby so you need to create custom widget. Flutter doesn't have that